# Covering space for figure $8$ space, such that $\chi(G) = 0$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

The covering space for the figure $8$ can be thought of as a graph.  Is there a covering such that $\chi(G) = 0$ (i.e the number of vertices equals the number of edges)?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $\Gamma_1$ is a graph and $\Gamma_2$ is a $n$-sheeted covering space of $\Gamma_1$, then $\chi(\Gamma_2)=n \chi(\Gamma_1)$.